# Insert new entity via Automapper

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

Is it possible to use Automapper for creating a new entity in my new data model (Entity framwork)?

I am currently working on  data migration and there are some changes in tables (in new destination data model).
I can map all those new changes to new data model. But what about completely a new entity in Destination contex?
In new data model  i have a newtable  without any relationship with other tables .
i wish i could do some thing like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<null, newDataModel.newtable >();
```

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a dbSet of new data model in dbContext:

```
public DbSet<NewModel> NewModel{ get; set; }
```

After that you can map old entities to new ones, and if in some cases you need to create a new entity you can try

```
CreateMap<OldModel, NewModel>()
    .ConvertUsing(arg =>
    {
        return new NewModel()
        {
            // setting properties values
        };
    });
```

Here `arg` is a source object. But if you need to fill new models not from old ones you do not need automapper